# Loading Facebook Page Tab URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

have created a Facebook App,As we know Facebook app have 2 `URLs.` `Page Tab URL and Application URL`.In my code if I redirect user to Page Tab URL it gives me FacebookGraphMethod Exception.May be I need to redirect with additional parameters.Anyone who can help with this\
For Example
The Page Tab URL is `abc.com/main.php`
From main.php I navigate to xyz.php
Now I want to go back to main.php what should I do,I even tried `window.location.href`
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use top.location.href to redirect to page tab.

```
<?php 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='".$fbpagetaburl."';</script>";
  exit; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you first need to add your App to a page. Then, you can access it on this page by clicking he app icon (or to an URL like this: `http://facebook.com/{{page_username}}/app_{{app_id}}`).

You can get the page username using this method on FB API:

```
$profile = $facebook->api('/' . $PageInfo['page']['id'], 'GET');
$page_username = $profile['username'];
```

To add the app to a page, you can use the `add page tab dialog`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

Comment: I have already did added into my page.What If I want to redirect my user back to this Page Tab?

Comment: Then, like I said, you use this URL: `http://facebook.com/{{page_username}}/app_{{app_id}}`

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I just tried this.Throughout the app the URL remain the same..I tried http://facebook.com/{{page_username}}/app_{{app_id}} ,but it just load the same page and doesn't redirect me to PageTab URL

Comment: I added instructions on how to get the `page_username` from the Graph API if you don't want to hardcode it.

Comment: Words inside `{{var}}` are variable where you put the real information

Comment: I believe page_username appears in the addressbar

Comment: Exactly..I put the variables like page username and App_ID

Comment: Then, can you paste in how you redirect the user? `header()` won't work in an iframe. You'll need to print a script tag containing `window.location.top = {{page tab url}}`

Comment: I used window.location.href,but when i redirect it to the main page ,It throws exception

Comment: Edit your post with real code snippets and more information, it'll be easier.

Comment: Have you tried using top.location.href. This is the code that I use on index.php for page tab applications.
<?php
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='".$fbpagetaburl."';</script>";
 exit;
?>

Comment: @VishweshShetty please post it as answer so I can accept.Thanks